# JLabel transferhandler copy working but not move

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, move

I want to move text from one jlabel onto another, but for some reason, only copy is working and not move. I am using a transferhandler so in handler.exportAsDrag(comp, e, TransferHandler.MOVE); only TransferHandler.COPY works.

```
            add1 = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        add1.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("text"));
        add1.setBorder(b2);


        add2 = new JLabel("", JLabel.CENTER);
        add2.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("text"));
        add2.setBorder(b2);

            MouseListener listener = new DragMouseAdapter();

        add1.addMouseListener(listener);
        add2.addMouseListener(listener);

            panel2a.add(add1);

        panel2a.add(add2);
```

They are dragged using this private inner class

```
private class DragMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter
    {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            JComponent comp = (JComponent)e.getSource();
            TransferHandler handler = comp.getTransferHandler();

            //c.setOpaque(true);
            handler.exportAsDrag(comp, e, TransferHandler.MOVE);

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implementation of [TransferHandler.getSourceActions()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html#getSourceActions%28javax.swing.JComponent%29) by default returns `COPY` if the specified property exists and has a proper getter:

```
public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
PropertyDescriptor prop = getPropertyDescriptor(c);
if (prop != null) {
    return COPY;
}
return NONE;
}
```

As a result, when you specify `MOVE` in `exportAsDrag()` the handler decides the action is not supported.

You can override this method to add whatever actions your source supports. For example:

```
add1.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("text") {
    @Override
    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
        return COPY | MOVE;
    }
});
```

***EDIT: implement exportDone***

```
this.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler("text") {
    @Override
    protected void exportDone(JComponent source, Transferable data, int action) {
        if (action == MOVE){
            ((JLabel) source).setText("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
        return COPY | MOVE;
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to change it for more than one component at a time?
Instead of doing add1.set.... add2.set..... add3.set...., etc.?

Comment: For some reason it is still copying even though i made them all move

Comment: @rasen58 You may need to implement `TransferHandler.exportDone()`. Please post a sample of your code as [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: So would I put that function in my mousePressed function?
Also, what do i put in the middle argument. 
handler.exportDone(comp, e, TransferHandler.MOVE);
It says that it should be of type transferable, so what do I put there?

Comment: @rasen58 No, once drop completes, `TransferHandle` will call `exportDone()`. Its default implementation is empty. So, override this method, ie add: `((JLabel) source).setText("");`

Comment: In the oracle docs, [oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/TransferHandler.html), it says that exportDone takes three parameters. So where do i put the function, inside add1.setTransferhandler?

Comment: @rasen58 see last edit that demos `exportDone` implementation.

Comment: Thanks, I just figured it out before i saw your edit. Thank you for all your help, it now workds